# ListView crash application

Tags: android, listview

I want to create very simple `ListView` but unfortunately every time app crasehes.
This is my code:

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener {

    public static String[] daysArray = {"Ponedeljek", "Torek", "Sreda", "Četrtek", "Petek", "Sobota", "Nedelja"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, daysArray);

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i("Info", "CLICKED");
    }

}
```

Layout main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ListView android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT:**

```
02-18 14:56:51.549: D/dalvikvm(2618): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 68K, 6% free 3096K/3280K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
02-18 14:56:51.561: I/dalvikvm-heap(2618): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.202MB for 1127532-byte allocation
02-18 14:56:51.565: D/dalvikvm(2618): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 5% free 4195K/4384K, paused 4ms, total 4ms
02-18 14:56:51.581: D/AndroidRuntime(2618): Shutting down VM
02-18 14:56:51.585: W/dalvikvm(2618): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4d89b20)
02-18 14:56:51.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2618): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-18 14:56:51.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2618): Process: com.example.listsstudy, PID: 2618
02-18 14:56:51.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2618): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.listsstudy/com.example.listsstudy.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
02-18 14:56:51.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2618):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
02-18 14:56:51.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2618):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
02-18 14:56:51.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2618):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-18 14:56:51.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2618):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
02-18 14:56:51.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2618):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-18 14:56:51.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2618):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-18 14:56:51.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2618):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-18 14:56:51.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2618):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-18 14:56:51.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2618):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-18 14:56:51.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2618):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-18 14:56:51.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2618):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-18 14:56:51.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2618):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-18 14:56:51.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2618): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
02-18 14:56:51.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2618):     at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
02-18 14:56:51.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2618):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:293)
02-18 14:56:51.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2618):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
02-18 14:56:51.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2618):     at com.example.listsstudy.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
02-18 14:56:51.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2618):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
02-18 14:56:51.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2618):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
02-18 14:56:51.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2618):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
02-18 14:56:51.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2618):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Please post the LogCat error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

need to use

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

instead of:

```
android:id="@+id/listView"
```

If you use ListActivity. Or just try to use Activity, not ListActivity

EDIT:
my code;
Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
...
```

And in my class:

```
public class AnyNameHere extends ListActivity  {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate ( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView ( R.layout.listview );
            // do what you want here;
}
```

and it's working :)

Comment: Hmm got this:
`error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'id' with value '@id/list').`

Answer (score 3):

you are extending `ListActivity`. Your `ListView` has to have

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

as id.

Comment: I believe it's just @android:id/list

Answer (score 2):

You're ListView has the wrong ID.  From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html):

> To do this, your own view MUST contain a ListView object with the id
>   "@android:id/list" (or list if it's in code)

Comment: got error:
No resource found that matches the given name (at 'id' with value '@id/list').

Comment: You used android:id="@android:id/list" as the id in xml?

Answer (score 0):

Because of your setContentView method call.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to `entend ListActivity` to create your activity, as `MainActivity`, then your `ListView` xml must be identified the `android:id` with `list` as follows...

```
<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```